# How to use filter/includes to get the select input of a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in elementor and i'm trying to filter out some inputs. They have some hidden fields and some buttons they inject to the code. I am trying to retrieve only the inputs I need. I can filter out the hidden fields,buttons and return my textareas and text inputs with the below code. However I cannot figure out how to get my select inputs. Is there a different/better way to filter form inputs from the array?

```
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click',function(e){
   //Export2Word('pos_form','Test');
   const keep = ["select","textarea","text"]
   const f = document.getElementById('pos_form').elements;
   const f_data = Array.from(f);
   const filtered = f_data.filter(input => keep.includes(input.type));
   console.log(f_data);
   console.log(filtered);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], select, textarea')` should be enough:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fields = event.target.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], select, textarea');
  console.log(fields);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number"/>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="hidden"/>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You! I originally tried to keep it in the onclick of my button but was having some difficulties. Moving it to the form submit worked as you showed.